# Regex PHP word boundaries?

Tags: php, regex

Why doesn't this regex:

```
$match = preg_grep("%^\w{2,5}\b[a-zA-Z]%", $randarray);
```

return '123 Main street'? from a $randarray = array('123 Main Street');

these word boundaries are confusing me.When I type `%^\w{2,5}\b[a-zA-Z]\b%` also nothing happens...why?

Comment: what are you expecting to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A word boundary is not a character**

A word boundary is `\b`. A word boundary is not a space, or any character at all. It is the transition between a word and a non-word, so it's actually a point between characters, not a character itself.

If you want to match `123 Main street`, you will have to match a sequence of numbers, followed by a space, followed by (I think) one or more words. So something like

```
/^\w{2,5}(\s[a-zA-Z]+\b)+/
```

So the second group matches a space (that comes after the street number or the previous word of the name), a sequence of alphabetical characters, and a word boundary. It will match '123 main street', and just 'main street'.

**Greedy/ungreedy**

By default a regular expression is greedy and will match as much characters as possible. So in this case you won't actually need the word boundary at all. It won't match `str` if it can match `street`. So the following regular expression will have the same effect as the one above, (unless you add some ungready modifier).

```
/^\w{2,5}(\s[a-zA-Z]+)+/
```

But for an ungreedy regular expression it is important. Compare

```
^\w{2,5}(\s[a-zA-Z]+?)+
```

and

```
^\w{2,5}(\s[a-zA-Z]+?\b)+
```

The first one will match `123 M`, while the second one will match `123 Main street` again.

**Test your regexes**

If you like to test this or other regular expressions, you can visit http://www.phpliveregex.com/ It allows you to test regular expressions to see how they work with a couple of `preg_*` functions.

Comment: OK thanks, one more question isnt the transtion in my example '123 Main Street' between 123 and a space a word boundary because space is a non-word right?Does that count as a word boundary?

Comment: No, a space is a character by itself. A word boundary is not a character but a position between characters. You use Word boundaries to ensure you match a whole word. For instance if I want a word to end in 'street', I can write `[a-z]*street\b`. It will match any (alphabetical lowercase) word that ends in street, regardless whether there is a space or any other non-word letter after it or not, but it won't match 'streets'.

Comment: @AlexAdic [Read about `\b` here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) special the "three different positions that qualify as word boundaries".

Comment: I tried to add some extra info and a little more structure to the answer.

Comment: Thank you GolezTrol thats the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression:

```
^\w{2,5}\b[a-zA-Z]
```

Will match "123 Main Street" up until here:

```
123 Main Street
   ^
```

*Note that the word boundary actually takes up no space at all, so the caret is positioned at the character that follows it.*

At that point, it tries to match `[a-zA-Z]` and fails. Instead, you should match space:

```
^\w{2,5}\s+[a-zA-Z]
```

The word boundary will naturally occur due to the transition between `\w` and `\s` so I've taken that out.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you want to validate that your subject "starts with a word between 2 and 5 chars long"

`preg_match('%^\w{2,5}\b[a-zA-Z]*%', '123 Main Street')`

(you're missing the `*`)

Comment: The `*` changes the semantics of the expression; it should at the very least be `+` but then it would fail to match as well.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I understand your point but I don't think that the downvote is fair when I started my statement with "Assuming". Doesn't my RegExp match what I **assumed**?

Comment: No, it won't. \b is a word boundary, not a space. Your regex won't read past the space, and because it is allowed to have 0 length words, it just matches `123`, not `123 Main Street`.

Comment: You already know what OP wants to match, so there's no need to assume otherwise. Also, if that's your assumption why not make the expression `\w{2,5}\b`?

Comment: @Jack I didn't (what OP wants to match) at the write time but, again, I rest my case. `^\w{2,5}\b` allows chars not in `[a-zA-Z]` right after the `\b`.

Comment: Yeah, `\w{2,5\b` allows characters that aren't letters after the word boundary, but so does `\w{2,5}\b[a-zA-Z]*`, that's my point.